# How to add loading on button during showing message: Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I am using `[Element-ui][1]` to build my front end.

I want to do:

1. While I will click a button a `alert()` message will show.
2. As long as the message will show, at that moment button loading will show.
3. I have added `setTimeout()` to `true` the loading. But not working!!!

Button:

```
<el-button type="primary" @click="open" :loading="isLoading">Enable Cart Tracking</el-button>
```

Data:

```
data() {
  return {
    isLoading: false
  }
},
```

Methods:

```
open() {
 this.$message({type: 'success', message: 'Cart Enabled'}); 
 setTimeout(function()
 { 
   console.log("Hmmmm");
   this.isLoading = true 
  }, 2000);
}
```

`Hmmmm` is showing and `$message` is also showing. But Button loading is not working!!!

Comment: Can you try changing `setTimeout(function()` to `setTimeout(() =>` to see if that works?

Comment: Oh brother. Yes. It is working. Can you please give me this as answer with description??

Comment: You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work). Basically when you use the 'function' keyword it changes what 'this' means.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)